# If/else conditional in Mathematica

Tags: conditional, matlab

I am a beginner in Mathematica. How can I turn the following Matlab commands  into Mathematica commands.

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
d=4;
if ((a<4 || b>5) && ((c==3 || d<=6) && (c+d<10)))
    a=10;
    b=20;
    c=30;
    d=40;
elseif ((a<=2) && (c==3 || d<=6))
    a=100;
    b=200;
    c=300;
    d=400;
else
    a=1000;
    b=2000;
    c=3000;
    d=4000;
end
```

Comment: Take a look at `Which`.

Comment: As I said I am a beginner in Mathematica. Kindly explain in more details.

Comment: Type `Which` in your notebook, then press `F1`.

Comment: In command Which[test1,value1,test2,value2,…], there is one value correspond to each test, however I want to have  multiple values correspond to each test. I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Your `else` doesn't return more either. You are making assignments there, do the same in `Which`.

Comment: Use semicolons (`CompoundExpression`); `Which[x > 0, a = 1; b = 2;, x < 0, a = 3; b = 4;, True, a = b = 0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of your if expressions using *Mathematica*'s [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html):

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;

Which[
  (a < 4 || b > 5) && ((c == 3 || d <= 6) && (c + d < 10)),
    a = 10; b = 20; c = 30; d = 40,
  (a <= 2) && (c == 3 || d <= 6),
    a = 100; b = 200; c = 300; d = 400,
  True,
    a = 1000; b = 2000; c = 3000; d = 4000
]
```

Note the use of compound expressions linked together using [`;`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html). See also [Understand that semicolon is not a delimiter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/27951).

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematica commands If and And should do the trick:

```
If[query, "if true, run this code", "if false, run this code"]
```

Using two If functions should do the trick. The function And should be pretty self-explanatory.

As a beginner, putting a question mark (?) before any function will give you a rundown of it.